# Serializing data from db in flat structure

Tags: c#, serialization, dynamic

I have a list of objects which contains a parameter name and his value.

I want to generate serialize it in a single object with parameter name as property name and value as the value

example:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of two parameters { Name = "name1", Value = "value1" }, { Name = "name2", Value = "value2" }

I want to seriliaze an object like this:

new { "name1" = "value1", "name2" = "value2"  }

any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` if the serialization library being used supports it.

For instance using `Json.NET` to serialize a `Dictionary(string, string)` to the JSON format:

```
var parameters = new List<Parameter>
{
    new Parameter { Name = "name1", Value = "value1" },
    new Parameter { Name = "name2", Value = "value2" }
};

var objToSerialize =
    parameters
    .ToDictionary(
        param => param.Name,
        param => param.Value);

// Use Json.NET to serialize the dictionary
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objToSerialize);

// Outputs
// result = {"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"}
```